# $\sum_{j=1}^n\langle x_j,y_j\rangle \leq \sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^n\langle x_j,x_j\rangle} \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \langle y_j,y_j\rangle}$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

I'm trying to prove that $\sum_{j=1}^n\langle x_j,y_j\rangle \leq \sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^n\langle x_j,x_j\rangle} \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \langle y_j,y_j\rangle}$, where $\left(V, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle \right)$ is an inner product space and $x_1, x_2, ...$ and $y_1, y_2,...$ are sequences of elements of $V$.

My attempt: 
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\langle x_j,y_j\rangle \leq \sum_{j=1}^n\langle x_j,x_j\rangle^{1/2}\langle y_j,y_j\rangle^{1/2} \leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \langle x_j,x_j\rangle\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \langle y_j,y_j\rangle\right)^{1/2}.$$

I'm not sure if the first inequality holds for an arbitrary inner product space. The second inequality is based on Cauchy. Am I correct?

Comment: "I'm not sure if the first inequality holds for an arbitrary inner product space" Yes, it's exactly the Cauchy inequality.

Comment: Actually you are applying Cauchy twice, for different spaces and inner products. But it's still OK.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 Thank you. I applied Cauchy twice for different inner product spaces so I think I also need to show $[a,b] = \sum_{j=1}^n \langle a,a \rangle^{1/2} \langle b,b \rangle^{1/2}$ is also an inner product?

Comment: Actually You don't. You use in this step the standard inner product from $R^n$: $\langle x, y\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n x_iy_i$. And the Cauchy inequality is then $|\sum_{k=1}^n x_iy_i| \le (\sum_{k=1}^n x_i^2)^{1/2}(\sum_{k=1}^n y_i^2)^{1/2}$. You simply use it for vectors $(\langle x_1, x_1\rangle^{1/2},...,\langle x_n, x_n\rangle^{1/2})$ and $(\langle y_1, y_1\rangle^{1/2}),...,\langle y_n, y_n \rangle^{1/2})$ instead of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 The problem doesn't say that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is from $V\times V \to \Bbb R^n$ so I think the space of the domain can be any field. Is it correct to say that we use the standard inner product from $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Don't mistake the scalar product which I used above for the original scalar product of the problem. I was probably not so subtle to use the same notation. Let's say that the standard scalar product from $R^n$ ist $\langle,\rangle_2$. Then You have to use the Cauchy inequality for two different scaral products. In first step You use the orginal scalar product and in the second step the standard scalar product from $R^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably write it as the answer, I think it would be clearer this way.

So, you have some scalar product $\langle,\rangle$ on $V\times V$. As with every scalar product, you have the Cauchy inequality: 
$$|\langle x,y\rangle| \le \langle x,x\rangle^{1/2}\langle y,y\rangle^{1/2}.$$

It is valid for all possible $x,y$, so also for $x_i,y_i$. Hence you have for each $i$: $$|\langle x_i,y_i\rangle| \le \langle x_i,x_i\rangle^{1/2}\langle y_i,y_i\rangle^{1/2}.$$
Summing up you then have $\sum_{i=1}^n|\langle x_i,y_i\rangle| \le \sum_{i=1}^n\langle x_i,x_i\rangle^{1/2}\langle y_i,y_i\rangle^{1/2}$.

In the next step you consider another space: $\Bbb R^n$. In this space there is the standard scalar product and then the Cauchy inequality with respect to this product. It says that for each $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ you have 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n |x_iy_i|\le 
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$

As it holds for all $x,y$, it also holds for $x=(\langle x_1,x_1\rangle^{1/2},...,\langle x_n,x_n\rangle^{1/2})$ and $y=(\langle y_1,y_1\rangle^{1/2},...,\langle y_n,y_n\rangle^{1/2})$ which are simply the vectors from $\Bbb R^n$. Now for these concrete vectors, Cauchy says that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x_i,x_i\rangle^{1/2} \langle y_i,y_i\rangle^{1/2}\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x_i,x_i\rangle\right)^{1/2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \langle y_i,y_i\rangle\right)^{1/2}.$$ 
This proves the second inequality.